# Change Google colab language setting

Tags: settings, google-colaboratory

How to change Colab interface from French to English? I can not find this setting. this is my problem. The interface: 
[image]

Comment: I think mostly are english speaker working in France dealing with Azery and French language...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think that in section "Aide" the last option should be "Voir en anglais"

EDIT: `Aide` -> `Afficher en anglais`

Comment: Aide > Afficher en anglais

Comment: Thank you!!! ^^.  This helped me.  
I add a comment for other languages : 
 [ Colab menu / Help / View in English ]

Answer (score 18):

Select `Aide` > `Afficher en anglais`.
Goodluck!

Answer (score 11):

The language presented is based on browser settings, so you'll want to change the language settings in your browser.

Instructions for Chrome are here:
https://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Language-in-Google-Chrome

Answer (score 11):

hl parameter is used to set the page language. Add ?hl=en at the end of the URL of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is change your google chrome setting where there is a prefered language, that the google web will try to show pages in when google think it is necessary. When is necessary nobady knows.